# Android enterprise policy - how to use managed play store in Whitelist mode with big number of apps?

Tags: android-management-api, android-enterprise, android-enterprise-features

I just got to know that we can not use more than 1050 apps in Whitelist mode.
When I tried to add 1500 apps, I got an error: `too many apps. Maximum allowed 1050, actual 1500`

I know I'll need more apps but can not go in Blacklist mode since we are not allowing apps other than these 1500.

Anyone - any inputs on how to handle this scenario?

example policy :

```html
{
  "applications": [
    list of 1500 apps
  ],
  ...
  "playStoreMode": "WHITELIST"
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is a bad way to handle things, better use the Blacklist option and block the apps which are not required rather than whitelisting thousands of apps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, currently there is no way to increase the maximum number of apps allowed.  However, there is currently a feature request that is filed to change the limit but there is no guarantee when this will be worked on.

I suggest joining the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/release-notes) mailing list to keep you posted on the latest updates.